# How can I solve a Java Not-class-found Exception?

Tags: java, python, bioinformatics, fastq

I'm new in bioinformatics and I'm trying to run a pipeline that uses the program FastQC v0.11.3. I downloaded the program locally on a linux server (no sudo permissions). As far as I know, FastQC is a java written program and needs Java versions 1.6 or higher. 
When I check my Java version `java -version`, it returns: `openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14 LTS`

But when I try to run fastqc, either in my pipeline or alone, it returns this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.FastQCApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.FastQCApplication
```

Do you know how can I solve this? Maybe the Java version is not compatible with fastqc?
Any idea is helpful,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have downloaded the source code instead of the binary. As is described in this thread

https://github.com/s-andrews/FastQC/issues/19

Binary can be downloaded from

http://www.bioinformatics.babraham.ac.uk/projects/fastqc/fastqc_v0.11.8.zip

Comment: Thank you for your answer Daniel. I tried this but it didn't solve the problem. I get the same error. I think maybe the Java Environment installed on the server is unable to find this fastqc class? Maybe i need to set the classpath somehow?

Comment: When scanning for the documentation, I see this for linux: Linux:  

We have included a wrapper script, called 'fastqc' which is the easiest way to 
start the program.  The wrapper is in the top level of the FastQC installation.  You 
may need to make this file executable:

chmod 755 fastqc

..but once you have done that you can run it directly

./fastqc

Comment: Yes I did that and when i run "./fastqc" it returns the same error

Comment: Try first to use Java 8, since you seem to be using java 11 and alot has changed since java 9. If that doesn't work try setting the path like this: sudo ln -s /path/to/FastQC/fastqc /usr/local/bin/fastqc